# WebTestClient always return status 500 on exception test case Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient, spring-webclient

Im struggling with testing controller of WebFlux app. Test always returns 500 even though I mock status 404. I read that adding onErrorResume solves this problem because otherwise error is handled in AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler but this doesn't solve my problem. Endpoints work fine when working working with them in swagger.

**Service code**

```
        return githubWebClient.get()
                .uri(("/users/{username}/repos"), username)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(httpStatusCode -> httpStatusCode.value() == 404,
                        error -> Mono.error(new GithubUserNotFoundException("Github api did not find user: " + username)))
                .bodyToFlux(Repository.class)
                .onErrorMap(Throwable.class, throwable -> new Exception("plain exception"))
                .flatMap(this::fetchBranchesForRepository)
                .filter(repository -> !repository.fork());
    }
```

**Controller advice code**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(GithubUserNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ExceptionMessage handleGithubUserNotFoundException(GithubUserNotFoundException ex){
        ExceptionMessage exceptionMessage = ExceptionMessage
                .builder()
                .message(ex.getMessage())
                .status(404)
                .build();
        log.error("Exception has been occurred", ex);
        return exceptionMessage;
    }
```

**Test code**

```
    @Test
    void shouldThrowException_WhenApiCantFindUser() {
        String user = "test";

        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/users/" + user + "/repos"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.notFound()));

        webTestClient.get()
                .uri(user)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isNotFound();
    }
```

**Console logs**

```
2024-02-16T11:34:38.652+01:00  INFO 92904 --- [     parallel-1] pl.hubert.task.client.GithubClient       : Fetching repositories for user: test
2024-02-16T11:34:38.749+01:00 ERROR 92904 --- [     parallel-1] i.n.r.d.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders  : Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider, fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS resolutions on MacOS. Check whether you have a dependency on 'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos'. Use DEBUG level to see the full stack: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library
2024-02-16T11:34:38.888+01:00 ERROR 92904 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [63e1e91b] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/api/github/test"

java.lang.Exception: plain exception
    at pl.hubert.task.client.GithubClient.lambda$getUserRepositories$2(GithubClient.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler pl.hubert.task.controller.GithubController#getGithubReposByUsername(String) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/github/test" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at pl.hubert.task.client.GithubClient.lambda$getUserRepositories$2(GithubClient.java:33) ~[main/:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Flux.java:7239) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorResume$29(Flux.java:7292) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:256) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2236) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:280) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:232) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:89) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:415) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:446) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:500) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:782) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.15.jar:1.1.15]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-02-16T11:34:38.910+01:00 ERROR 92904 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.w.reactive.server.ExchangeResult   : Request details for assertion failure:

> GET /api/github/test
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]

No content

< 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR Internal Server Error
< 

0 bytes of content (unknown content-type).


Status expected:<404 NOT_FOUND> but was:<500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR>
Expected :404 NOT_FOUND
Actual   :500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<404 NOT_FOUND> but was:<500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR>
```